# Global pip referenced within a conda environment

Tags: pip, conda

To summarize, I create and activate a conda environment with just pip installed. Then I list the pip packages within the environment and all my global packages are installed. I check where pip is pointing, and it is correctly pointing to the newly created environment. So why does it list my global packages? Furthermore, I confirmed that I can load the packages. Any help is much appreciated! You can see all the code I ran here (within zsh prompts):

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ conda create -n pip_test_env pip
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/ethankeller/miniconda3/envs/pip_test_env

  added / updated specs: 
    - pip


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.4.16-0       conda-forge
    certifi:         2018.4.16-py36_0  conda-forge
    ncurses:         6.1-0             conda-forge
    openssl:         1.0.2o-0          conda-forge
    pip:             18.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    python:          3.6.5-1           conda-forge
    readline:        7.0-haf1bffa_1    conda-forge
    setuptools:      40.0.0-py36_0     conda-forge
    sqlite:          3.20.1-0          conda-forge
    tk:              8.6.8-0           conda-forge
    wheel:           0.31.1-py36_0     conda-forge
    xz:              5.2.3-0           conda-forge
    zlib:            1.2.11-h470a237_3 conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate pip_test_env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ conda activate pip_test_env
(pip_test_env) ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ which pip
/Users/ethankeller/miniconda3/envs/pip_test_env/bin/pip
(pip_test_env) ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ pip list
Package                  Version  
------------------------ ---------
aide-design              0.0.12   
alabaster                0.7.11   
atomicwrites             1.1.5    
attrs                    18.1.0   
Babel                    2.6.0    
certifi                  2018.4.16
chardet                  3.0.4    
codecov                  2.0.15   
coverage                 4.5.1    
cycler                   0.10.0   
docutils                 0.14     
idna                     2.7      
imagesize                1.0.0    
Jinja2                   2.10     
kiwisolver               1.0.1    
latexcodec               1.0.5    
MarkupSafe               1.0      
matplotlib               2.2.2    
more-itertools           4.2.0    
numpy                    1.14.5   
oset                     0.1.3    
packaging                17.1     
pandas                   0.23.3   
Pint                     0.8.1    
pip                      18.0     
pipenv                   2018.7.1 
pluggy                   0.6.0    
py                       1.5.4    
pybtex                   0.21     
pybtex-docutils          0.2.1    
Pygments                 2.2.0    
pyparsing                2.2.0    
pytest                   3.6.3    
pytest-cov               2.5.1    
python-dateutil          2.7.3    
pytz                     2018.5   
PyYAML                   3.13     
requests                 2.19.1   
ruamel.yaml              0.15.44  
scipy                    1.1.0    
setuptools               40.0.0   
six                      1.11.0   
snowballstemmer          1.2.1    
Sphinx                   1.7.6    
sphinx-rtd-theme         0.4.0    
sphinxcontrib-bibtex     0.4.0    
sphinxcontrib-disqus     1.1.0    
sphinxcontrib-websupport 1.1.0    
urllib3                  1.23     
virtualenv               16.0.0   
virtualenv-clone         0.3.0    
wheel                    0.31.1   
(pip_test_env) ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ 
(pip_test_env) ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ pip --version
pip 18.0 from /Users/ethankeller/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

As you can see, `which pip` and `pip --version` show two different locations. Why? How do I use the correct (the environment) pip package?

Answer (score 7):

You have answered your own question.

Look carefully at:

```
(pip_test_env) ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ which pip
/Users/ethankeller/miniconda3/envs/pip_test_env/bin/pip

(pip_test_env) ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ pip --version
pip 18.0 from /Users/ethankeller/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

It is picking up the pip executable from your conda environment, but pip itself is picking up it's internals from `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip`

There are many references to this issue:

- https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7173
- https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/448
- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668
- https://github.com/kushaldas/peps/pull/1/files
- https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9688

Till there is an official solution out, you can do either of the following:

```
echo "include-system-site-packages=false" >> $CONDA_PREFIX/pyvenv.cfg
```

OR:

```
export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
```

More references:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#isolation-from-system-site-packages

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments and the two "More references" you posted, the default configuration for include-system-site-packages is false. So how would adding that file change anything? I haven't set it to true... I did this anyways and it still has the strange behavior. And now, after pip 18 installs, I can't run "pip list" because it complains that pip._internal is missing. When I revert to 9.0.3, this is fixed but the other behavior persists. Suggestions?

Comment: Pip made a breaking change after release 10. You can read about you error at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599

Comment: If I were you, I would just move ~/.local/lib/python3.6/ to a backup directory and start from scratch